# TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [Moran,Mr.James] of <class 'str'>

Tags: python, pandas, slice

> TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on  with these indexers [Moran,Mr.James] of

This is a studying video tape, I don't have their data. I added some data which can be used in my own data.  It runs very well when I print data index, but when I try to slice data from index it can't run and gives me some error information

[image: Mydata/image]

```py
import pandas as pd
# will return a new DataFrame that is indexed by the values in the specified column
# and will drop that cloumn from the DataFrame
# without the PannengerId dropped

# DataFrame来指定一个索引值

passenger_data = pd.read_csv('titanic/train.csv')
print(type(passanger_data) )
passenger_ticket = passanger_data.set_index('Name',drop=False) # 把ticket当成一个索引
print(passenger_ticket.index) # 打印index 值

#
# 目前怀疑是数据的问题，一下索引都失败了
# 具体问题详

print('\n\n\n\n=========================')
#Slice using either bracket notation or loc[]
passenger_data["Moran,Mr.James":"Sandstrom,Miss.Marguerite Rut"]

# Specific ticiket
passanger_data.loc["Moran,Mr.James":"Sandstrom,Miss.Marguerite Rut"]

# Select list of movies
tickets  = ["Sandstrom,Miss.Marguerite Rut","Moran,Mr.James","Rice,Master.Eugene"]
passenger_data.loc[tickets]
```

The answer form computer

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index(['Braund, Mr. Owen Harris',
       'Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)',
       'Heikkinen, Miss. Laina',
       'Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)',
       'Allen, Mr. William Henry', 'Moran, Mr. James',
       'McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J', 'Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard',
       'Johnson, Mrs. Oscar W (Elisabeth Vilhelmina Berg)',
       'Nasser, Mrs. Nicholas (Adele Achem)',
       ...
       'Markun, Mr. Johann', 'Dahlberg, Miss. Gerda Ulrika',
       'Banfield, Mr. Frederick James', 'Sutehall, Mr. Henry Jr',
       'Rice, Mrs. William (Margaret Norton)', 'Montvila, Rev. Juozas',
       'Graham, Miss. Margaret Edith',
       'Johnston, Miss. Catherine Helen "Carrie"', 'Behr, Mr. Karl Howell',
       'Dooley, Mr. Patrick'],
      dtype='object', name='Name', length=891)




=========================

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-a5b969b8a3ba> in <module>
     13 print('\n\n\n\n=========================')
     14 #Slice using either bracket notation or loc[]
---> 15 passenger_data["Moran,Mr.James":"Sandstrom,Miss.Marguerite Rut"]
     16 
     17 # Specific ticiket

F:\Software\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2959 
   2960         # Do we have a slicer (on rows)?
-> 2961         indexer = convert_to_index_sliceable(self, key)
   2962         if indexer is not None:
   2963             return self._slice(indexer, axis=0)

F:\Software\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in convert_to_index_sliceable(obj, key)
   2356     idx = obj.index
   2357     if isinstance(key, slice):
-> 2358         return idx._convert_slice_indexer(key, kind="getitem")
   2359 
   2360     elif isinstance(key, str):

F:\Software\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _convert_slice_indexer(self, key, kind)
   3188             if self.is_integer() or is_index_slice:
   3189                 return slice(
-> 3190                     self._validate_indexer("slice", key.start, kind),
   3191                     self._validate_indexer("slice", key.stop, kind),
   3192                     self._validate_indexer("slice", key.step, kind),

F:\Software\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _validate_indexer(self, form, key, kind)
   5069             pass
   5070         elif kind in ["iloc", "getitem"]:
-> 5071             self._invalid_indexer(form, key)
   5072         return key
   5073 

F:\Software\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _invalid_indexer(self, form, key)
   3338             "cannot do {form} indexing on {klass} with these "
   3339             "indexers [{key}] of {kind}".format(
-> 3340                 form=form, klass=type(self), key=key, kind=type(key)
   3341             )
   3342         )

TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [Moran,Mr.James] of <class 'str'>
```

Comment: I think you wrong use DataFrame variable, need `passenger_ticket` like `passenger_ticket.loc["Moran,Mr.James":"Sandstrom,Miss.Marguerite Rut"]`, because in `passenger_ticket` is created `index` by `Name` column

Answer (score 0):

You are slicing on the wrong dataframe:

```
passenger_data["Moran,Mr.James":"Sandstrom,Miss.Marguerite Rut"]
```

is what you are doing, but the actual index is written into a different dataframe

```
passenger_ticket["Moran,Mr.James":"Sandstrom,Miss.Marguerite Rut"]
```

or alternatively also possible should be

```
passenger_ticket.loc["Moran,Mr.James":"Sandstrom,Miss.Marguerite Rut"]
```

PS: as already mentioned by @jezrael, I just realized...